# Update and insert TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can i modify TSQL update statement below to insert `partid` of the source table is not in the partid field of Item ID ='500224' in destination table. if doesn't exist I need to insert.

```
USE [DBNAME];
GO
    UPDATE m
    SET [partId] = a.[partId] 
select * FROM
    [SourceTable] m
    INNER JOIN 
    [DestTable] a
    ON m.[bomItem] = a.[ItemId]
    AND m.bomEntry = a.bomEntry AND  m.bomRev = a.rev  WHERE
    m.bomRev=a.rev AND m.partId <> a.partid AND m.lineNbr = a.bomEntry ;
  Go
```

In Source Table

[image]

In Destination Table

[image]

For Example in pictures above partid `100280` doesn't exist in Destination table i want to add that and keep all others the same.

Comment: You can't do this with single query. Starting from SQL Server 2008R2 there is the MERGE statement which can do thrick.

Comment: Aside: Answers and comments are providing various means to achieve your desired end. Whatever you choose, go off and study up on _transactions_ and _isolation levels_. You'll want to ensure that the entire operation occurs atomically and that you haven't introduced a _race condition_. You can start [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx). (Note that `MERGE` is not atomic without appropriate locking. See [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the missing partid to the destination table, by using `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check.

```
INSERT INTO [DestTable] (bomItem, bomRev, bomEnty, lineNbr, dType, partId, revId, qty)
SELECT ST.ItemID, ST.rev, ST.bomEnty, ST.lineNbr, 0 AS dType, ST.partid, NULL AS revId, ST.qty
FROM [SourceTable] ST
LEFT JOIN [DestTable] DT ON DT.bomItem = ST.ItemID AND DT.partid = ST.partid
        AND DT.bomRev = ST.Rev AND DT.bomEntry = ST.bomEntry -- remove these conditions if not need
WHERE DT.partid IS NULL
```

Since few of the columns is mismatching between the two tables, I have added proper column names in the `SELECT`

Comment: How can i combine with the update statement and Catch duplicate  i get something like `Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 21
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MIBOMD_KEY_0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object`

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx

You'll want to use the IN operator:

```
SELECT partId FROM Source WHERE partID NOT IN (SELECT partID FROM Destination)
```

This will give you a list of all partIDs that don't appear in the Destination table, you can integrate this query into an UPDATE or INSERT query as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM destinationTable WHERE partID=’SomeValue’)
UPDATE destinationTable 
SET (..)
 WHERE Column1=’SomeValue’
ELSE
    INSERT INTO destinationTable 
VALUES (…)

Answer (score -1):

```
Insert into destTab(bomItem, bomRev, bomEntry, partId, qty)
Select Itemid, rev, bomEntry,partid, qty 
from sourceTab as s 
where not exists (select 1 from destTab as d where d.bomItem=s.Itemid and d.partId=s.partId)
```

Comment: You need to properly format your code; what you posted is unreadable.

Comment: You should leave a kind of comments for future readers. Code-only answer (even if it is correct) may mean nothing. Even **E = mc<sup>2</sup>**.